# Reverse of `;` in find command

Tags: vimrc, search

When I do something like:

- `f` `G`

To find the next G on the line, I can press `;` to find the next occurrence. However, once I've passed one, is there a way to find the previous occurrence? Likewise with doing capital `F` `G` ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not `:h ;` and on the next line find `,` ?

Comment: @BLayer I guess that, ultimately, every single question has got to be asked at a certain point in time...

Comment: @Biggybi Heh. I would counter with an earlier question asking the same thing but haven't found one yet (though I've found a number that contain the answer such as https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/how-to-scroll-through-a-really-long-line/2308#2308 )

Comment: @BLayer It looks like vim's complexity together with the many ways to phrase a question makes this forum virtually infinite (I hope my English is at least understandable). I'll sleep on it, good luck finding a duplicate!

Comment: @Biggybi Understandable sentiment about this place. From the standpoint of the question asked here Vim's help is the polar opposite....doesn't get much easier. Cheers.

Comment: @BLayer possibly https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15359/10604 ? Perhaps a little closer at least

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah. That looks like a good dup to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The opposite of `;` is `,` to find the previous occurrence.

It works with both `t` and `f` searches.

Of course, this will be inverted with `T` and `F`.

Thus, to go backwards, you could chose to only use `t` and `f` together with `,` : this is as many keystrokes as using capital letters and keeps cycling consistent in every case.